# php file upload says invalid file?

Tags: php

I am trying to upload a video file and want it to be saved in a folder called upload. Upload is the is the root directory of the website, where I have img css js etc.

What is wrong with the code, thank you?

```
         $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "mp3", "mp4", "wma");
        $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

         if ((($_FILES["upload"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
            || ($_FILES["upload"]["type"] == "audio/mp3")
         || ($_FILES["upload"]["type"] == "audio/wma")
           || ($_FILES["upload"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
          || ($_FILES["upload"]["type"] == "image/gif")
           || ($_FILES["upload"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"))

           && ($_FILES["upload"]["size"] < 20000)
           && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))

               {
                 if ($_FILES["upload"]["error"] > 0)
              {
              echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["upload"]["error"] . "<br />";
              }
               else
                 {
             echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["upload"]["name"] . "<br />";
                 echo "Type: " . $_FILES["upload"]["type"] . "<br />";
               echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["upload"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
                echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

              if (file_exists("upload" . $_FILES["upload"]["name"]))
                 {
                echo $_FILES["upload"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
                   }
             else
               {
                   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"],
                 "/upload" . $_FILES["upload"]["name"]);
                   echo "Stored in: " . "/upload" . $_FILES["upload"]["name"];
                 }
              }
                  }
                  else
                    {
              echo "Invalid file";
                     }
              ?>

            </body>
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <head>
               <title>File Uplaod</title>
             </head>

                 <body>

           <form action="Upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
             <label for="file"><span>Filename:</span></label>
              <input type="file" name="upload" id="file" /> 
               <br />
               <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
               </form>

                </body>
               </html>
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug this at all?  If it goes into the `else` block, that means one of the conditions is false.  Try to `var_dump($_FILES["upload"]);` to see what's going on.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the folder you are trying to write to has the correct permissions?

Comment: 1) Format your code to be human-readable.  2) Determine which condition *you wrote* is causing this to happen.

Comment: Pleas give us more info. What is wrong is not a possible questions. What error message did you get, what happened exactly and what was expected. Reduce your shown code to the parts actually concerned. Debug until you found the culprit. AND THEN ask a quastion on how to solve this!